# How can I install Forge into Eclipse using CMD?

Tags: eclipse, command-prompt, gradlew, minecraft-forge

This is what I did:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click in the forge folder
2. Clicked "open command window here"
3. Typed in "`gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse`"
4. Once it's done there's an error message that says:

> you are running the 
>   setupDecompWorkspace task and an IDE/build task in the same command. Do them separately."
>   
>   What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run two seperate commands instead of both at the same time.
You need to run:

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
```

and you then:

```
gradlew eclipse
```